# Play Scala Slick example (v.2.8.x) with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, play-slick

for weeks I'm trying to get slick running with evolutions for Postgres (and eventually with `codegen` for the Tables.scala file) and it is extremely frustrating because the official documentation stops after the essential basic setup and anything that can be found elsewhere on the internet what goes a bit deeper is outdated. It seems that the framework changes a lot after every release and you cannot use older code snippets.

In order to keep things simple, I ended up in cloning the official `play-samples` repo and step by step change that to work with Postgres instead of the used H2 in-memory db.

Here is a link to the [play-scala-slick-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-slick-example)

The only thing I changed is in the [build.sbt#L11](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/109e570db7514803dda939c4e0c6d1ade750b781/play-scala-slick-example/build.sbt#L11):

- I replaced the `h2` dependency with a postgres dependency:
  `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.19",`
- and I added the `jdbc` dependency (according to their documentation) - but this causes a binding issue, so I'm not sure that this dependency should be really used

Then I changed the config to connect to local dev DB at the [application.conf#L66-L68](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/109e570db7514803dda939c4e0c6d1ade750b781/play-scala-slick-example/conf/application.conf#L66-L68)

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_local_test_db?currentSchema=play_example&user=postgres&password="
```

When I run the application with the JDBC connection and try to access it in the browser it reports this exception:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(DBModule.scala:39):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.DBApiProvider)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4).
  at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:15):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)
```

And when I run it without the `jdbc` dependency (I saw some hints on stackoverflow that this might cause the exception above) then it displays a warning and eventually runs into a timeout.

```
[warn] c.z.h.HikariConfig - db - using dataSourceClassName and ignoring jdbcUrl.
```

Does anyone know what is missing here to tell it to use the JDBC URL?

Answer (score 1):

I was going through similar problems for getting the `Play` to work with `Postgres`.

The connections to the database should be configured with a pool from `HikariCP`. The pasted configuration, as it can be implied from the build file, gets `Slick` to use `HikariCP`.

Here you go with my base and let me know if it works:

Contents of `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._

import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

val SlickVersion = "3.3.2"

name := “play-slick"

version := "6.0.0"

//val PlayVersion = "2.8.5"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.18",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % SlickVersion,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.8.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "4.4.1" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.2.1",
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.2.6",
  "com.iheart" %% "ficus" % "1.4.7",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "8.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "8.0.1",
//"com.enragedginger" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % "1.8.2-akka-2.6.x",
  "com.enragedginger" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % "1.8.3-akka-2.6.x",
  "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap" % "1.5.1-P27-B4",
  specs2 % Test,
  ehcache,
  guice,
  jdbc,
  filters
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

routesImport += "utils.route.Binders._"

// https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/105
TwirlKeys.templateImports := Seq()

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation", // Emit warning and location for usages of deprecated APIs.
  "-feature", // Emit warning and location for usages of features that should be imported explicitly.
  "-unchecked", // Enable additional warnings where generated code depends on assumptions.
  "-Xfatal-warnings", // Fail the compilation if there are any warnings.
  //"-Xlint", // Enable recommended additional warnings.
  "-Ywarn-dead-code", // Warn when dead code is identified.
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen", // Warn when numerics are widened.
  // Play has a lot of issues with unused imports and unsued params
  // https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6690
  // https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/105
  "-Xlint:-unused,_"
)

//********************************************************
// Scalariform settings
//********************************************************

scalariformAutoformat := true

ScalariformKeys.preferences := ScalariformKeys.preferences.value
  .setPreference(FormatXml, false)
  .setPreference(DoubleIndentConstructorArguments, false)
  .setPreference(DanglingCloseParenthesis, Preserve)
```

The database configuration which should be added to `application.conf`, provided that `Postgres` is configured to use encrypted connection. I used `letsencrypt`.

```
#include "database.conf"



db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/users_db?ssl=true&sslmode=require"
db.default.username=${?DATABASE_USER}
db.default.password=${?DATABASE_PASSWORD}

db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"




fixedConnectionPool = 5

database.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

Sample from `UserDAOImpl`, for the signature and the imports:

```
package models.daos

import java.util.UUID

import javax.inject.Inject
import models.User
import play.api.db.Database

import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }

/**
 * Give access to the user object.
 */
class UserDAOImpl @Inject() (db: Database)(implicit executionContext: DatabaseExecutionContext) extends UserDAO {


  /**
   * Finds a user by its user info.
   *
   * @param userInfo The user info of the user to find.
   * @return The found user or None if no user for the given user info could be found.
   */
  def find(userInfo: UserInfo) =
    
    Future {
      val c = db.getConnection()
      val statement = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?;")
      statement.setString(1, userInfo.email)
      if (statement.execute()) {
        val resultSet = statement.getResultSet
        if (resultSet.next()) {
          val userID = resultSet.getString("userid")
          val firstName = resultSet.getString("firstName")
          val lastName = resultSet.getString("lastName")
          val affiliation = resultSet.getString("affiliation")
          val roleTitle = resultSet.getString("roleTitle")
          val fullName = resultSet.getString("fullName")
          val email = resultSet.getString("email")
          val avatarURL = resultSet.getString("avatarURL")
          val activatedStr = resultSet.getString("activated")
          val activated: Boolean = activatedStr match {
            case "f" => false
            case "t" => true
            case _ => false
          }
          statement.close()
          c.close()
          Some(
            User(
              UUID.fromString(userID),
              firstName = Some(firstName),
              lastName = Some(lastName),
              affiliation = Some(affiliation),
              roleTitle = Some(roleTitle),
              fullName = Some(fullName),
              email = Some(email),
              avatarURL = Some(avatarURL),
              activated))

        } else {
          statement.close()
          c.close()
          None
        }
      } else {
        statement.close()
        c.close()
        None
      }
    }

}
```

Place this `DatabaseExecutionContext` file in the same directory as your `dao` files.

```
package models.daos

import javax.inject._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext

/**
 * This class is a pointer to an execution context configured to point to "database.dispatcher"
 * in the "application.conf" file.
 */
@Singleton
class DatabaseExecutionContext @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "database.dispatcher")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution user. But wouldn't it mean that instead of `play-slick` and `play-slick-evolutions` it would then use `play-silhouette`? So I would lose the evolutions functionality? Or could I also use your approach without `play-silhouette`?

Comment: no you can just omit the `silhouette`. This solution is just for the database connection, and it has nothing to do with `silhouette` itself. I added `silhouette` simply because I thought you might need that at a later stage for establishing encrypted connection with authenticated users, which is a common feature of most projects.

Comment: @Phoen I updated the answer to remove silhouette from it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. Thanks to user who pointed me in the right direction, where I found what the actual 2 problems are.

First in my `application.conf` had the wrong parameters and second I indeed needed to get rid of the `jdbc` dependency.

When the slick db config looks like this, then it will work:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fugu_test?currentSchema=play_example&user=postgres&password="
```

The "...properties..." was missing in both 2 last lines for the `driver` and `url`. It seems that what I had was from an older slick version.

Comment: It’s better to put the username and password in your environment variables rather than in your database url. Does your solution use a connection pool?